# What is the App.info.id for in Meteor mobile-config.js file?

Tags: meteor

I'm currently in the process of trying to deploy an app I'm building to the app stores and I can't figure out what is the purpose of meteor's App.info.id? What should I put here? What is the importance of it?

The documentation [here](http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#submitting-ios) isn't entirely clear.

```
App.info({
  id: "????",
  name: "My Application",
  version: "1.0.0"
});
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Meteor reads a mobile-config.js file in the root of your app directory during build, and uses the settings specified there to generate Cordova’s config.xml.

With the properties of the object passed to `App.info`, Meteor generates the [Cordova config.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) file for you application.

The `id` property, according to the [Cordova Docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#widget):

> Specifies the app's reverse-domain identifier, and the version its full version number expressed in major/minor/patch notation.

Comment: Thanks a million! That was super helpful.